# Pandas getting next available datetime index if desired one doesn't exist

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

So I have a DataFrame, f, with weekly indexes:

```
            Open   High    Low  Close      Volume
Date    


2017-07-24  5.05  5.120  5.010   5.19  16306737.0
2017-07-31  5.31  5.475  5.280   5.24  45182199.0
2017-08-07  5.69  5.740  5.640   5.67  10167161.0
2017-08-14  5.65  5.680  5.440   5.76  28296416.0
2017-08-21  5.49  5.605  5.480   5.55  16126060.0
2017-08-28  6.00  6.030  5.940   5.95  19398271.0
2017-09-04  5.86  5.965  5.845   6.01  20218389.0
2017-09-11  5.98  6.030  5.830   5.98  15812289.0
2017-09-18  5.71  5.770  5.540   5.81  30786508.0
2017-09-25  5.16  5.190  5.090   5.17  13641128.0
```

I want to parse a datetime object to it, if that datetime object exists in the index then I'll use the data in that row, otherwise if it doesn't exist in the index then grab the next row after where my parsed date would be.

E.g: if I parse `f.loc[(datetime.datetime(2017, 09, 07)]` 
then that isn't in the index so I want it to grab the row

`2017-09-11  5.98  6.030  5.830   5.98  15812289.0`

since that is the next indexed date after 7 September.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One straightforward solution is using `np.searchsorted`:

```
df.iloc[[np.searchsorted(df.index, '2017-09-07')]]  

            Open  High   Low  Close      Volume
Date                                           
2017-09-11  5.98  6.03  5.83   5.98  15812289.0
```

---

**Details**

```
df

            Open   High    Low  Close      Volume
Date                                             
2017-07-24  5.05  5.120  5.010   5.19  16306737.0
2017-07-31  5.31  5.475  5.280   5.24  45182199.0
2017-08-07  5.69  5.740  5.640   5.67  10167161.0
2017-08-14  5.65  5.680  5.440   5.76  28296416.0
2017-08-21  5.49  5.605  5.480   5.55  16126060.0
2017-08-28  6.00  6.030  5.940   5.95  19398271.0
2017-09-04  5.86  5.965  5.845   6.01  20218389.0
2017-09-11  5.98  6.030  5.830   5.98  15812289.0
2017-09-18  5.71  5.770  5.540   5.81  30786508.0
2017-09-25  5.16  5.190  5.090   5.17  13641128.0

df.index.dtype
dtype('<M8[ns]')
```

Comment: And if it comes after the last one? (-;

Comment: Great answer btw

Comment: @piRSquared I didn't consider that... :( (not sure how to handle that actually)

Comment: it's a good point piRSquared but luckily for me it will never be after the last one.

Comment: I knew there would be a simple solution, thankyou @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ